# Multilingual App Toolkit fails with no error information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual, multilingual-app-toolkit

I added the MAT to our project so that we could more easily add additional languages in the future. It was working completely fine and then I pulled down some new code from our TFS server and it stopped building. Our other developer who has the same code on his machine has no problems building.

All I've got to go on is

```
"One or more errors occurred."
"Generation of language RESX files failed."
"Multilingual App Toolkit build completed with errors."
```

These three errors all point to the same Microsoft.Multilingual.ResxResources.targets file and tell me exactly nothing about what has actually gone wrong. I know that support for ASP.NET MVC is fairly new in the MAT, are there some common errors that could cause this? My googling has not found anything relevant yet.

You would think they would put at least some information into an error output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reinstalling the MAT and reenabling it on my project I was given a small clue in the form of a build warning for one particular .xlf file about how it wasn't able to generate the file because of access.

Turns out my entire project had somehow become set to readonly.

And so another easy fix to a problem created by poor error output.